# CSS getted away with view.blade.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a `.blade.php` view that is nice and well designed with css, but when I put a variable like `{{$data}}` or even inside a for each loop `{{$d->col1}}` the css design get away.

What is the reason to be

```
@foreach($data as $d )     
  {{$d->price}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: please include your html/css code, and point out where exactly you get an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected myself
I changed

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

And the problem solved.